# How to Add Custom Data to Highchart.js Tooltip

Tags: highcharts

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/opgp10mj/1/) and let me  know how I can add some custom data from an array to tooltip in highchart?

```
var extras = ["Values More Than 1000", "Values More Than 2000", "Values More Than 3000", "Values More Than 4000", "Values More Than 5000"];
```

As you can see the array length is equal to the column numbers so the `extras[0]` with go with tooltip for column `1`

some thing like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the tooltip with the formatter option.

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        var index = this.series.points.indexOf(this.point);
        return extras[index] + ': ' + this.y;
    },
    style: {
        width: 250,
        fontSize: '15px'
    }
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/opgp10mj/3/

Comment: Thanks Stefano Castriotta,